# Returning XML from web api changes field name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have this class which I am trying to return as XML from my web api method:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class LoggedInUser
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public short RoleID { get; set; }

    public short UserStatusID { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastLoginDateTime { get; set; }

}
```

Web API method is simple:

```
[HttpGet]
public LoggedInUser Me()
{
    var user = new LoggedInUser() { FirstName = "Test"  };
    return user;
}
```

This is what I get in XML when I hit the method from browser:

```
<_x003C_FirstName_x003E_k__BackingField>Test</_x003C_FirstName_x003E_k__BackingField>
```

Notice how FirstName changes to some other field name. This is due to the presence of `[Serializable]` attribute which I need is as this is the same class which is used to store info in session when Session state is `outProc`

How can I fix this such that even though the `Serializable` attribute is present it would return the field name in response same as class definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the `XmlMediaTypeFormmatter` of Web API uses the `DataContractSerializer`.

When this serializer serializes auto-properties, it adds the infamous `xxx_BackingField` to the serialized properties. To avoid this you can do two different things:

- decorate all the autoproperties with `[DataMember]`, and keep using the default `DataContractSerializer`
- Change the xml media type formatter default serializer to use `XmlSerializer` instead. You can change the configuration in global.asax like this: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;`
  See [MSDN reference for XmlMediaTypeFormatter.UseXmlSerializer Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.xmlmediatypeformatter.usexmlserializer%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for more information.

Using an anonymous type, like suggested in the other answer, avoids the problem because the anonymous class doesn't have a `[DataContract]` attribute. The problem is that, with that option, you always have to use anonymous types, and that can require a lot of typing, and even be error prone.

Answer (score 1):

When `Serializable` Attribute is required I always return an anonymous type.

```
public dynamic Me()
{
    var user = new LoggedInUser() { FirstName = "Test" };
    return new {FirstName = user.FirstName};
}
```

Comment: This isn't the best solution, but a shorcut to avoid the problem. Please, se my answer.

Comment: You are right... using DataContract/DataMember attribute is the better solution IF you have access to the sourcecode of the models. Another solution would be the usage of AutoMapper.

Comment: But you have a different option, which is using the XmlSerializer, and that will work even if you don't have access to the models. Using AutoMapper, or ValueInjecter also requires creating the new clasess, maintaining them, and so on. I prefer to restict its use to DTOs or view models,not to avoid problems with attributes. The fact is that serializing to JSON, or XML always gives headaches...

Comment: Yes it can give headaches. This is why you always need to carefully consider what you change to solve a problem. Returning a dynamic seems to be a quick fix in the first place, but could be the right choice to solve a problem at a particular point before changing the entire serializing process or models. I´m not saying that you are wrong and for @TCM your solution fitted his needs. However, you cant say that returning dynamics isnt the best solution if you dont know the environment or architectural decisions behind an application. :-)

Comment: I guess you know the pros and cons already but I paste the link anyway. Cheers. http://web.archive.org/web/20130430190551/http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/